# How can I create a file read/write permissions in /mnt/?

Tags: linux, file, go, operating-system, copy

I tried `os.Create()` but it gives permission denied. It is expected result but how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Run your script with root permission.

Comment: What are you trying to create? You may need to change the permission of the directory or run as different user. As a last resort, you may need to run it as root (but this should usually be avoided if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Check first if you have a security setting that would prevent the creation of any file (root or not) in /mnt.

See "[Can't create/write to file '/mnt/temp/something' (Errcode: 13)](https://serverfault.com/a/672773/783)"

It involves adding a profile in `/etc/apparmor.d` in order to allow any file to be created.
See "[Ubuntu AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor)".

Answer (score 0):

To create a new file use ioutil package

https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go?s=2518:2586#L66

To change an existing file's permission use the os package
which can help you here with file permission,
make sure that you execute your binary with the appropriate permission, otherwise you will get an error.

```
if err := os.Chmod("some-filename", 0644); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```